# Sizing html elements relatively while align properly

Tags: html, css

In this case, there are multiple input fields across multiple rows.

Each field width given as no of characters that field should support

If field width is 10, it should support 10 characters
There is a fixed margin between fields

Ex:
First row have 3 input fields with widths as (10, 10 ,10)

Second row have 4 input fields with widths as (10, 5, 5, 10)

Third row have 2 input fields with widths as (15, 15)

In this case summation of field's widths is 30 in all three rows

So left and right ends of row's should be in a same vertical line

How to calculate field's widths?

Is that possible to keep alignment between rows?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easily with [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids). Your html may change, but the solution lay on grid.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 5fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

section:nth-child(1),
section:nth-child(2),
section:nth-child(3),
section:nth-child(4),
section:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

section:nth-child(8),
section:nth-child(9) {
  grid-column: span 3;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>10</section>
  <section>10</section>
  <section>10</section>
  <section>10</section>
  <section>5</section>
  <section>5</section>
  <section>10</section>
  <section>15</section>
  <section>15</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that case in the question is just a example. The field sizes are dynamic and those are input fields. They should also support 'n' no of characters if it's width is 'n'.

Comment: Edit your question to post your html and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex grow, for example like this:

```
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="flexItem10">…</div>
  <div class="flexItem5>…</div>
  <div class="flexItem5>…</div>
<div class="flexItem10">…</div>



.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}



.flexItem5 {
  flex-grow: 5;
}

.flexItem10 {
  flex-grow: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Field sizes, no of rows and no of fields in a row are dynamic. Case in the question is just a example. And those fields need to support 'n' no of characters when it's width is 'n'.